# Why is Entity Framework claiming another instance of entity type 'IdentityUser' cannot be tracked because another instance is using it?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor Server and trying to change the roles an application user belongs to. I pass the user and the list of a roles class to the implementation to assign or delete roles.

Here is the implementation:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser_DTO> UpdateRoles(ApplicationUser_DTO objDTO, List<RoleSelected> rolesSelected)
{
    foreach (var role in rolesSelected)
    {
        if (role.Selected)
            // This line fails as it says another Id is being tracked.
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(objDTO, role.PossibleRole);
        else
            await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(objDTO, role.PossibleRole);
    }

    return objDTO;
}
```

And this is the `RoleSelected` class:

```
public class RoleSelected
{
    public string? PossibleRole { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

So all possible roles are encapsulated and whether or not the user should belong to that role. I enabled `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` and is says another instance with the key value '{ Id: IDString }' is already being tracked. I don't understand how this is happening as this is the correct `IDString` that I am trying to modify.

I tried creating a new `IdentityUser` and the error remained. The `ApplicationUser_DTO` extends the `Identity` class. What else could it be tracking here? Let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share code for `AddToRoleAsync` and `RemoveFromRoleAsync`?

Comment: Because what it's saying is almost certainly correct.  What type of `DbContext` are you using?  What does `_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(objDTO, role.PossibleRole);` look like.  There can be a multitude of reasons for the error, but without more context and code, there's no way to know why.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I was able to answer this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this problem myself. Apparently, Entity Framework became confused when I passed the ApplicationUser_DTO and then tried to update it. What I did to solve it was just pass the Identity of the user and then lookup the user.  The code looks like this:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser_DTO> UpdateRoles(string id, List<RoleSelected> rolesSelected)
{
    //I just passed the id and looked it up and presto, it worked!
    ApplicationUser appUser = _db.ApplicationUsers!.Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    foreach (var role in rolesSelected)
    {
        if (role.Selected)
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser!, role.PossibleRole);
        else
            await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(appUser!, role.PossibleRole);
    }
    return new ApplicationUser_DTO();
}
```

Comment: The only problem remaining is that you are still doing the same with the roles. Here you should also be using `RoleDto`s as parameter, and look them up in the `DbContext.Roles` before calling `AddToRoleAsync`